# Events on Write Side of CQRS for Saga/Process Managers

Tags: events, nservicebus, cqrs

I understand process managers (aska as sagas) consume events (and commands) and produce/send commands on the read side of CQRS.

I have three questions:

1. How do process managers generally get the events in CQRS implementations?  Do they usually subscribe to something like an eventbus OR are they directly sent the events?
2. Does this delivery mechanism (no matter what it is) need to be reliable (at least once) delivery? It would seem a problem if events were to be missed (e.g. due to a crash).
3. Are there any examples where a process manager listens for events from ARs that it has not directly or indirectly sent a command to?  E.g. just listening for specific events.

I am asking these question about event distribution with regards to the write side / domain model in CQRS, not the read / query side.

Thanks,
Ashley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, they register for the events they like to receive on the event bus.
2. Yes, it needs to be reliable.  For, the event bus usually has a "at least once" delivery guarantee, i.e., it guarantees that each event is delivered to each registered endpoint at least once.  The process managers also need to make sure that their state changes and the commands they send to the command bus are also stored reliably when they acknowledge the receipt of the event.  In [our own](https://github.com/JEEventStore/JEECQRS/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/jeecqrs/sagas) CQRS implementation, we use JEE transactions for that part.
3. Sure, I would even say this is the standard.  A very simple example is some notification system (e.g., notification mails) when something in the domain happened.

Comment: Great answer Alexander, thank you. This was my understanding as well but I wanted to be sure.  The read side seems to get more "airtime" than the write side and especially its eventbus.

I can understand that process manager state / changes must also be recorded / persisted reliably.  

However, I thought commands were a bit more flexible, and didn't need reliable delivery (e.g. if there was no resulting events or the system crashed they could try again after a timeout period).

Comment: You'll need a reliable commandbus for commands issued by sagas:  Suppose a saga receives an event, changes its state and issues a new command and then persists its state and acknowledges successful receipt of the event.  Suppose now the command is lost - then the command is lost, but the saga is in a state where it assumes it has sent the command.  If your commandbus is not reliable, you can use a timeout mechanism (i.e., check for expected result of command after some time), but this requires reliable timeouts.

Comment: Thanks again Alexander. I understand about the commandbus (and was thinking of doing the timeouts but will consider further). Just a point about your notification system example. Figures on the Web suggest this would be done on the read side (although its not actually a query).  Do you agree (or not)?  Are there any other examples of process managers on the write side that wouldn't have specifically sent a command to an AR (or PM) but would be listening for an event?

Comment: Hmm, no, I think a saga that does not issue a command at all is not of any use on the write side (what would be its purpose?).  As for the notification system, our notification sagas listen for specific events  and issue suitable "send notification via XY" commands that are processed by the application side, but not any ARs. See this example: https://github.com/JEEventStore/JEECQRS-Quickstart-Sample/blob/master/ejb/src/main/java/org/jeecqrs/example/quickstart/sagas/orders/OrderShippedMessagingSaga.java

Comment: Sorry Alexander, I wasn't clear. In many cases, I assume, a process manager sends a command to an AR and then waits for an appropriate event.  What I was asking was if there were examples of a PM listening for appropriate events and then sending a command(s) without having previously sent the event-producing AR a command.  As a result of this, in particular, the AR doesn't know who will be listening for and acting upon the event.  I hope that makes it clear and thanks for your patience. It's a bit convoluted but I would like an example of where the event-producer is unknown to the PM.

Comment: The ARs should never know who will be listening for and acting upon the event - this is not desired (loose coupling).  Actually, sagas are always triggered by events...   The following `OrderShipmentSaga` might be an example:  It listens to `InvoiceIssued` and `PaymentArrived`, raised by two different ARs and sends a whole new `ShipOrderCommand` to the `Order` AR. https://github.com/JEEventStore/JEECQRS-Quickstart-Sample/blob/master/ejb/src/main/java/org/jeecqrs/example/quickstart/sagas/orders/OrderShipmentSaga.java

Comment: Alexander,
I wanted to understand implementation https://github.com/JEEventStore/JEECQRS. If possible share any documentation.
-Prakhyat M M